# ElasticSearch 5 won't find documents with keyword including space

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl

I/m indexing documents with the following format:

```
{
"title": "this is the title",
"brand": "brand here",
"filters": ["filter1", "filter2", "Sin filters", "Camera IP"]
"active": true
}
```

Then a query looks like:

```
'query': {
            'function_score': {
                'query': {
                    'bool': {
                        'filter': [
                            {
                                'term': {
                                    'active': True
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        'must': [
{
                                'terms': {
                                    'filters': ['camera ip']

                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I can't return any document with "Camera IP" filters (or any variation of this string, lowercase and so on), but Es returns the ones with filters: "Sin filters".

The index is created with the following settings. Note that "filter" fields will fall under default template and is of type keyword

```
"settings":{
         "index":{
            "analysis":{
                "analyzer":{
                    "keylower":{
                        "tokenizer":"keyword",
                        "filter":"lowercase"
                    }
                }
            }
         }
    },
    "mappings": {

        "_default_": {
            "dynamic_templates": [
                {
                    "string_as_keywords": {
                        "mapping": {
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            **"analyzer": "keylower"** # I also tried with and without changing this analyzer
                            },
                        "match": "*",
                        "match_mapping_type": "string"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "integers": {
                        "mapping": {
                            "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "match": "*",
                        "match_mapping_type": "long"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "floats": {
                        "mapping": {
                            "type": "float"
                        },
                        "match": "*",
                        "match_mapping_type": "double"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
}
```

What I'm missing? It's strange it returns those with "Sin filters" filter but not with "Camera IP".

Thanks.

Comment: which ES version are you using?

Comment: I'm with 5.1.1 now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want the filters to be lowercase and not be tokenized.  I think the problem with your query is that you set the type of the strings a "keyword" and ES will not analyze these fields, not even changing their case:

> Keyword fields are only searchable by their exact value.

That is why with your setting you can still retrieve the document with a query like this: `{"query": {"term": {"filters": "Camera IP"}}}'`.

Since you want the analyzer to change the casing of your text before indexing you should set the type to `text` by changing your mapping to something like this:

```
{"settings":{
  "index": {
        "analysis":{
            "analyzer":{
                "test_analyzer":{
                    "tokenizer":"keyword",
                    "filter":"lowercase"
                }
            }
        }
     }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
        "dynamic_templates": [
            {
                "string_as_keywords": {
                    "mapping": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "index": "not_analyzed",
                        "analyzer": "test_analyzer"
                        },
                    "match": "*",
                    "match_mapping_type": "string"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your filter `'filters': ['camera ip']` looks for `camera ip` whereas in the mapping you have the field `filters` as type `keyword` which elasticsearch looks for an exact match. So, in order to find that field you will need to have an exact string that you index for a match. If your use case doesn't require an exact match change the type to `text`, for which elasticsearch analyzes before indexing. More on text datatype [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html) and keyword datatype [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html)